# I am facing issue with Hibernate/lucene search with spring-boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Actually I want to implement lucene search in my project but I am getting this following exception after adding hibernate-search-orm.jar 
I am using spring-boot 2.0.2, spring-data-JPA, and my-sql as database plz help me for this

> 08-17-2018 19:22:49 [WARN] --- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am Using Spring data JPA so if I added  hibernate-search-orm jar  this error is coming

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the database driver jar in your pom.xml. Please add appropriate jar and build again.

e.g. If you are using postgres, you may need to add this in your pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

for oracle, please add the one below.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please make sure you have your database properties configured in application.properties file.